# How to begin transactions, In Spring boot JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a composite unique constraint in the database and i wish to violate it inside the transaction but it will be upheld after i call commit.

It's pretty basic database transaction, but i am not aware how to achieve it using JPA.

I have already tried `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` on my `@org.springframework.stereotype.Service` class and also at the method level.

but the moment i call `userRepository.save(userEntity)` it throws

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: (conn=380) Duplicate entry ...'
```

controller

```
    @PostMapping("/save")
    @Transactional
    fun createUser(
        @RequestHeader("token", required = true) subject: String,
    ): ResponseEntity<*> {
        val id = extractId(subject)
        return userService.save(id)
    }
```

service

```
    @Transactional
    fun save(id: String): ResponseEntity<*> {
     val validatedUser =  getValidatedUser(id)
     return ResponseEntity<User>(validatedUser, HttpStatus.CREATED)
    }

   @Transactional
   fun getValidatedUser(id: String): User? {
      var list = listOf(User(id))
      val newUser = //some logic to generate user
      userRepository.saveAll(list.plus(newUser)) // <--- where error happens
   }
```

Comment: Can you please share your Code? The way you describe sounds acually ok. Annotationg @Transactional on MethodLevel should be correct. Spring however can only open Transactions if the Method is public and called from outside the bean.

Comment: @GJohannes, thanks for your response i have added some abstracted code see if you find the issue, thanks again !

Comment: the mehtod `userService.save()` and `extractId()` is not shown. Where do you get your error and where would you expect it to be if transactions would work properly?

Comment: Oh my bad, I have updated the code `save()` is in the service
I get error at this line `userRepository.saveAll(list.plus(newUser))`

Comment: A couple of comments: Spring silently ignores the `@Transactional` annotation in controllers. Just a heads up as this is something that surprises most people. Also, spring-jpa is not an abstraction over JPA. You need to understand how JPA works without spring and also have a good knowledge of the code spring executes when you call methods such as `JpaReposository.saveAll()`.

Comment: You are already adding the user, then add that new use to the list again and save the same user twice... don't use `saveAll(list.plus(newUser))` (not even sure why you put that in a list) but do `userRepository.save(newUser)`.

Comment: i have to add 2 different users and hence i am using list. I have already tried adding each user individually i face the same issue.

Comment: Do you actually want to batch insert (insert multiple users)  at once (in one request) ?

Comment: no that is not the question, we have composite unique key which should be violated inside a transaction (have duplicate entry for some short duration) make them unique and commit.

Comment: Hi @Navneetkumar,

when you say `violate it inside the transaction` do you want to get an exception and handle the unique key inside `try catch`?

Comment: obviously not, that is the whole point to avoid any exception because its a transaction unless we call `commit` constraints shouldn't be checked.

Comment: Hi @Navneetkumar, Can you clarify what db constraints are on the user, what is on // some logic to generate user and what is the result of User(id)

Comment: some logic return a different user with different user ID, in `users relation` i have a column `mobile_number` and a `flag` if the number is verified (some internal business logic) or not and a `unique constraint` is 1 mobile number can have only 1 `true` flag.

Comment: Does it fail if you only save the result of User(Id)? And does it fail if you only save newUser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [DEFERRED constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html).

Simplified example (postgresql) that mimics your actions:

```sql
create table users (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(255) unique
);
start transaction;
insert into users(id, name) values(1, 'max');
insert into users(id, name) values(2, 'max'); -- fails here, despite the transaction
insert into users(id, name) values(3, 'paul');
commit;
```

using `deferrable` and `set constraints deferred`:

```sql
create table users (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(255) unique deferrable
);
start transaction;
set constraints all deferred;
insert into users(id, name) values(1, 'max');
insert into users(id, name) values(2, 'max'); -- no fail here
insert into users(id, name) values(3, 'paul');
commit; -- fails here ("deferred")
```

using `deferrable initially deferred` you can skip `set constraints deferred`:

```sql
create table users (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(255) unique deferrable initially deferred
);
start transaction;
-- no 'set constraints deferred' necessary
insert into users(id, name) values(1, 'max');
insert into users(id, name) values(2, 'max'); -- no fail here
insert into users(id, name) values(3, 'paul');
update users set name = 'bob' where id = 2; -- fixes constraint violation
commit; -- succeeds
```

So, the easiest solution would be to add `deferrable initially deferred` to your constraint definition.

Comment: Thanks this what i was missing, I kind of figured it but i am not sure mariaDB supports it since i am using MariaDB and not postgres. do you have any idea how to do it mariadb.

Comment: No you can't `deferred` a constrain int `INNO_DB` variants let it be `MySql` or `MariaDB` :(
https://www.draconianoverlord.com/2010/07/22/dammit-mysql.html/

Comment: https://jira.mariadb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/MDEV-26097

Answer (score -1):

1. Your database has composite unique constraint. So you can't insert the same data.
2. This error means that the program inserted the same data at runtime.This is not allowed.
3. I think there may be a problem of duplicate ID here.

   var list = listOf(User(id))
4. Because of 3, two user objects with the same ID are created in the next step of the code.So there was an error inserting into database.
5. You can output user object at the console and find out if there is the same userId object.

Answer (score -1):

```
// RollbackFor=Exception.class needs to be specified
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
fun save(id: String): ResponseEntity<*> {
 val validatedUser =  getValidatedUser(id)
 return ResponseEntity<User>(validatedUser, HttpStatus.CREATED)
}
```